# Jquery binding and unbinding events for anchor tags

Tags: jquery

I have anchor tags in my Page. And have .click() events written for some functionality ,
I wanted to disable the actions on Page Load and enable the actions on some button click.

For preventing actions i can use unbind("click"). But not able to bind as .Bind("click") requires function name.

Pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of worrying about detaching and reattaching events you could store the `href` in a `data-` attribute then set `href` to `#`. When your enable button is clicked we can restore the `href`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zhnx4/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<button id="enable">Enable</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').each(function () {
        disableAnchor($(this));
    });
    $('#enable').click(function () {
        $('a').each(function () {
            enableAnchor($(this));
        });
    });
});
function disableAnchor(a) {
    a.attr('data-href', a.attr('href'));
    a.attr('href', '#');
}
function enableAnchor(a) {
    a.attr('href', a.attr('data-href'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use on page load

```
$(function(){
    $("a").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```